# How to return a value if a specific iterated sub string *not* found in value?

Tags: python

I have an excluded substrings contain text file, which I want to iterate to check and return the input item without excluded substring.

Here I am using python 2.4 so below code to achieve this as `with open` and `any` is not working. but I am bound to hard code the substrings:

**Working Code:**

```
def filterJunk(x):
        return [i for i in x if not ('I' in i or 'am' in i or '#junk' in i)]

OutPutList = []
for x in InputstringsList:
    OutPutList.append(filterJunk(x))
```

**PROBLEM:**

BUT what if I need to exclude n numbers of substrings? obviously, I won't hardcode them all within the code, hence I want an alternate way so that I can read each substring from excluding file and assert the final value does not contain the same

If I could return a value if substring from the text file not found in value.

**For example**

To process:

```
InputstringsList = ["Icantbeapart_of_yourlist_asI_am_in_Junk", "youAre", "MeeToooo", "#junk"]
```

**Expected Output**

```
OutPutList = ["youAre", "MeeToooo"]
```

Comment: Could you be a little more clear about what inputs and outputs to this function would look like?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: what if I need to exclude n numbers of substrings? obviously, I won't hardcode them all within the code, hence I want an alternate way so that I can read each substring from excluding file and assert the final value does not contain the same.

Comment: Please show your code involving a file input..

Comment: Just updated the code of completed logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one-liner (not necessary the most optimal thing to do though):

```
[x for x in stringsList if not [e for e in excluded if e in x]]
```

or

```
from itertools import dropwhile
[x for x in stringsList if not list(dropwhile(lambda t: t not in x, excluded))]
```

Comment: I am restricted to use PRD installed python 2.4.x so as I mentioned: "any" is not working.

Comment: @RahulTrivedi Simply remove `any` - it's not required here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a helper function and the built-in [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function:

```
def filterJunk(x, excluded):
    def not_excluded(s):
        for ex in excluded:
            if ex in s:
                return False
        return True

    return filter(not_excluded, x)

stringsList = ["Icantbeapart_of_yourlist_asI_am_in_Junk", "youAre", "MeeToooo", "#junk"]
excluded = 'I', 'am', '#junk'

print filterJunk(stringsList, excluded)  # -> ['youAre', 'MeeToooo']
```

**Analysis**

Since my answer is considerably more than one line of code, you'd reasonably expect it to be slower than "one-liners" such as the two in [@AGN Gazer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47107842/355230). Whether that's true depends on what version of Python you're using. This can be seen by bench marking different algorithms, which I just did using some execution-timing test code I [threw-together](https://pastebin.com/DYZRLrKk)).

For Python 2.7.14 the results were:

```
Fastest to slowest execution speeds using Python 2.7.14
(10,000 executions, best of 3 repetitions)

AGN Gazer 1 :  0.009705 secs, rel speed  1.00x,   0.00% slower
  martineau :  0.012495 secs, rel speed  1.29x,  28.74% slower
AGN Gazer 2 :  0.045498 secs, rel speed  4.69x, 368.79% slower
```

But they are quite different for Python 3.6.3:

```
Fastest to slowest execution speeds using Python 3.6.3
(10,000 executions, best of 3 repetitions)

  martineau :  0.003329 secs, rel speed  1.00x,   0.00% slower
AGN Gazer 1 :  0.017841 secs, rel speed  5.36x, 435.99% slower
AGN Gazer 2 :  0.034160 secs, rel speed 10.26x, 926.29% slower
```

Comment: Pls 1 for a) correct answer and b) in my testing being more efficient than my one liners.

Comment: @AGN Gazer: That's very sportsmanlike of you—thanks—however things aren't quite that simple. See the **Analysis** section I just added to my answer. I'd say which one of our answers is the "best" depends on the environment it's used in. The OP's question isn't tagged python-2.x, but in it they mention they're using ancient Python 2.4.

Comment: I actually cannot even test anything in 2.4 (I don't have it and do not want to bother installing it) and your answer is perfectly fine. And I cannot take my upvote back anyway :)

Comment: @AGN Gazer: I'm also not going to install very old Python v2.4 just to test our answers to this question either. However I posted a link to my bench marking code in the update, so the OP can see what's best for themselves if they wish (and maybe even change their accepted answer `;¬)`.